# Complete Measures Associated with a Premeasure

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $X$, a $\sigma$-finite premeasure $\mu_0$ defined on an algebra $A$ of $X$. $\mu_0$ can induce an outer measure $\mu_0^*$ on $X$. That is, for every subset $E$ of $X$,
$$\mu_0^*(E)=\inf\{\sum_1^\infty\mu_0(A_j):A_j\in A, E\subset \bigcup_1^\infty A_j\}$$
Let $\sigma(A)$ be the $\sigma-$algebra generated by $A$ and $M_{\mu_0}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu_0^*$-measurable sets. We then can know that both $\mu_1=\mu_0^*|_{\sigma(A)}$ and $\mu_2=\mu_0^*|_{M_{\mu_0}}$ are measures. Is it true that $\mu_2$ is equal to the completion of $\mu_1$?

Let $\overline{\sigma(A)}$ be the completion of $\sigma(A)$ with respect to $\mu_1$. To answer the question above, it suffices to show that $\overline{\sigma(A)}=M_{\mu_0}$ (because there is a unique extension of $\mu_1$ to a complete measure on $\overline{\sigma(A)}$ and $\mu_2$ is a complete measure).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{N}=\{N\in \sigma(A):\mu_1(N)=0\}$. A set $S$ in $\overline{\sigma(A)}$ is equal to $E\cup F$ for some $E\in \sigma(A)$ and $F\subset N\in \mathcal{N}$. $E$ and $N$ are $\mu_0^*$-measurable. Hence, $\mu_0^*(F)=0$, so $F$ is also $\mu_0^*$-measurable. $S=E\cup F$ thus belongs to $M_{\mu_0}$, and $\overline{\sigma(A)}\subset M_{\mu_0}$.

Conversely, given $E\in M_{\mu_0}$. $E^c$ is also an element of $M_{\mu_0}$. By Exercise 18 in Chapter 1, Folland's Real Analysis, we know that there exists set $B\in A_{\sigma\delta}\subset \sigma(A)$ with $E^c\subset B$ such that $\mu_0^*(B-E^c)=0$. Similarly, there exists $D\in A_{\sigma\delta}\subset \sigma(A)$ with $E\subset D$ such that $\mu_0^*(D-E)=0$. Since $D-B^c\in \sigma(A)$, we have
$$\mu_1(D-B^c)=\mu_0^*(D-B^c)\leq \mu^*_0(D-E)+\mu^*_0(B-E^c)=0$$
Notice that $E=B^c\cup((D-B^c)\cap E)$, where $B^c\in \sigma(A)$ and $(D-B^c)\cap E\subset D-B^c\in \mathcal{N}$. This suggests that $E\in \overline{\sigma(A)}$ and $M_{\mu_0}\subset \overline{\sigma(A)}$.